# How to solve a math problem that is presented in a string format using the Shunting Yard algorithm Implementation in Java?

Tags: java

**Question:**
How to solve a math problem that is in a string format? The user will enter a math problem that starts with the word calculate. like "calculate 5 + 2" or "calculate 10 - 3" and the program needs to solve it. Attempted to resolve this using the Shunting Yard algorithm Implementation in Java.

Comment: Your actual question is *"how can this be improved"*.  That is too broad.  Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution Offered:**
A simple solution for the above problem mentioned would be something like this I presume. May need to add some additional functionality if you need to handle complex maths formulas.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator {
    private static final Map<String, Integer> OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE.put("+", 1);
        OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE.put("-", 1);
        OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE.put("*", 2);
        OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE.put("/", 2);
        OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE.put("^", 3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter a math problem starting with 'calculate': ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!input.startsWith("calculate ")) {
                System.out.println("Error: Input must start with 'calculate'");
                return;
            }
            String input_trimmed = input.trim();
            System.out.println("input_trimmed " + input_trimmed);
            String expression = input_trimmed.substring("calculate ".length());
            System.out.println("expression " + expression);
            try {
                validateExpression(expression);
                double result = evaluate(expression);
                System.out.println("Result: " + result);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid number in expression");
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: Division by zero");
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid expression ");

            }
        }
    }

    private static double evaluate(String expression) throws Exception {
        String[] tokens = expression.split("\\s+");
        if (tokens.length < 3 || tokens.length % 2 == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expression must contain at least one operator and two operands");
        }
        List<String> outputQueue = shuntingYard(tokens);
        return evaluatePostfix(outputQueue);
    }

    private static List<String> shuntingYard(String[] tokens) throws Exception {
        Stack<String> operatorStack = new Stack<>();
        List<String> outputQueue = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (isNumber(token)) {
                outputQueue.add(token);
            } else if (isOperator(token)) {
                while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && hasHigherPrecedence(operatorStack.peek(), token) && !operatorStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                    outputQueue.add(operatorStack.pop());
                }
                operatorStack.push(token);
            } else if (token.equals("(")) {
                operatorStack.push(token);
            } else if (token.equals(")")) {
                while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && !operatorStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                    outputQueue.add(operatorStack.pop());
                }
                if (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && operatorStack.peek().equals("(")) {
                    operatorStack.pop();
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Mismatched parentheses");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token: " + token);
            }
        }

        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
            if (operatorStack.peek().equals("(") || operatorStack.peek().equals(")")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Mismatched parentheses");
            }
            outputQueue.add(operatorStack.pop());
        }

        return outputQueue;
    }

    private static double evaluatePostfix(List<String> outputQueue) throws Exception {
        Stack<Double> operandStack = new Stack<>();

        for (String token : outputQueue) {
            if (isNumber(token)) {
                operandStack.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
            } else if (isOperator(token)) {
                if (operandStack.size() < 2) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
                }
                double rightOperand = operandStack.pop();
                double leftOperand = operandStack.pop();
                double result = evaluateExpression(leftOperand, rightOperand, token);
                operandStack.push(result);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid token: " + token);
            }
        }

        if (operandStack.size() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
        }

        return operandStack.pop();
    }

    private static boolean isNumber(String token) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(token);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isOperator(String token) {
        return OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE.containsKey(token);
    }

    private static boolean hasHigherPrecedence(String op1, String op2) {
        return OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE.get(op1) >= OPERATOR_PRECEDENCE.get(op2);
    }

    private static double evaluateExpression(double leftOperand, double rightOperand, String operator) {
        switch (operator) {
        case "+":
            return leftOperand + rightOperand;
        case "-":
            return leftOperand - rightOperand;
        case "*":
            return leftOperand * rightOperand;
        case "/":
            if (rightOperand == 0) {
                throw new ArithmeticException("Division by zero");
            }
            return leftOperand / rightOperand;
        case "^":
            return Math.pow(leftOperand, rightOperand);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid operator: " + operator);
        }
    }

    private static void validateExpression(String expression) {
        String[] tokens = expression.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            String token = tokens[i];
            System.out.println("Token " + token);
            if (isOperator(token)) {
                if (i == 0 || i == tokens.length - 1) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
                }
                String prevToken = tokens[i - 1];
                String nextToken = tokens[i + 1];
                if (!isNumber(prevToken) || !isNumber(nextToken)) {
                    System.out.println("error 1");
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
                }
            } else if (token.equals("(")) {
                if (i > 0 && isNumber(tokens[i - 1])) {
                    System.out.println("error 2");
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
                }
            } else if (token.equals(")")) {
                if (i < tokens.length - 1 && isNumber(tokens[i + 1])) {
                    System.out.println("error 3");
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
                }
            } else if (!isNumber(token)) {
                System.out.println("error 4");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how this program can be further improved?